# Dompdf gives me an empty pdf

Tags: pdf, yii2, dompdf

I installed `dompdf` using composer

`composer require dompdf/dompdf`

in my controller i have this

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

....

function actionPdf() {
   $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
   $dompdf->loadHtml('<h1>hello world</h1>');
   $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
   $dompdf->render();
}
```

but all i get is a blank PDF. When i check `app.log` i see this

```
2021-09-02 20:20:41 [127.0.0.1][262][-][error][yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException] yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in  on line 0. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php:373
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php(346): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(398): yii\web\Response->send()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\frontend\web\index.php(64): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}
```

Any Idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add `// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();`, Here is the docs: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#quick-start

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the exact proper `Yii` way, but in my case this works:

Note the `exit();` at the end.

```
// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf_options = new \Dompdf\Options();
$dompdf_options->setDpi(150);

$dompdf = new Dompdf($dompdf_options);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4');
      
// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

$attachment=false;

$options=[
    "Attachment" => $attachment
];

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('Informe de vehículo', $options);

exit();
```

I guess the problem is caused by how Yii renders the data. But by calling exit() you prevent any of that to happen.